# Javascript Deeplinking is not working, getting popup which I can not remove

Tags: javascript

If I click on the given link, it will take me to the chrome browser opening a popup with message "This site is opening another application" and if I allow it then gets another popup with "Something is wrong. the application couln`t be opened".

Chrome browser is not redirecting to mobile schema url and giving popup with "Something is wrong. the application couln`t be opened".

This only hapening in chrome browser. When I tried the same in safari it worked as expected.

I am using this small code. Only purpose is to redirect to the app if it is installed and if app is not sinatlled the ti twill redirect to app store.

```
var appLink = "mobile schema url";
if (feature != null) {
 appLink = "mobile schema url;
}
window.location.replace(appLink);
}
window.location.href = "app store url";
```

Expectation: Whenever link is clicked it should take you to the browser and asked for Opening the app if app is installed or take you to the app store if app is not installed.

Comment: I don't see why you use `window.location.replace`?

Comment: I honestly don't think you can detect whether an app is installed on a device via the browser - the security implications (let alone privacy via fingerprinting) would be terrible. You can only tell the browser to show if a meta tag of an application is detected and the browser will show this without telling you. If you forward, the browser won't tell you the results either. I could be wrong, but it would surprise me.